# Cannot display the selected image from mobile storage (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My code is working fine for selecting images from the phone, but I can't see a preview before uploading it, why? what's wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private static final int PIC_ID = 1;
Button uButton, dButton;
EditText firstText, secondText;
ImageView firstImage, secondImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uButton);
    dButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dButton);

    firstText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstText);
    secondText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.secondText);

    firstImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.firtsImage);
    secondImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.secondImage);

    firstImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    uButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    dButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.firtsImage:
            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(imageIntent, PIC_ID);
            break;
        case R.id.dButton:
            break;
        case R.id.uButton:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == PIC_ID && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
       Uri selected = data.getData();
        firstImage.setImageURI(selected);

    }
}
```

and my activity_main.xml file is

```
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">


   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/firtsImage"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:layout_width="150dp"
   android:layout_height="150dp" />


   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/firstText"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


   <Button
       android:id="@+id/uButton"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Upload"/>




   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/secondImage"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="150dp" />


   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/secondText"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


   <Button
       android:id="@+id/dButton"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="download"/>
```

I've googled it until I got a headache found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following:

```
Uri imageUri = data.getData();
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
firstImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```